# Moving files to a single folder - filename with spaces?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file I am using to move all items out of one folder (and subfolders) into a single folder `C:\Temp`

Folder structure is:

```
C:\VIDEO\My Video 1\My Video 1.mkv
C:\VIDEO\MyVideo2\MyVideo2.mkv
C:\VIDEO\My.Video.3\My.Video.3.mkv
```

My current command(s) in batch file:

```
@echo on & for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.mkv /s /b') do move %%~fa "C:\Temp"
```

All files move successfully except for "`My Video 1.mkv`". I think this must be because of the spaces in the filename and/or folder name.

How can I fix my command so that it also moves this file/folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put `""` around move target.

```
@echo on & for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.mkv /s /b') do move "%%~fa" "C:\Temp"
```